# Problema al poder traer de la base de datos una consulta grupal en especifico-- LARAVEL 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

estoy empezando en esto de programacion y me cuesta entender ciertas cosas. Quiero hacer que la base de datos solo me traiga los valores que en la tabla 'estado' sea igual a 1 ya que esas son las vendidas [image: aqui se puede ver que la tabla es rifas_ventas y lo que quiero es que si me traiga todos estos valores, pero quiero que las unicas que vengan son las que su estado sea igual a 1]

Answer (score 0):

recomiendo crear una vista (`view`) en la DB de esa consulta.

Luego aplicar los filtros en laravel:

```
$estado = 1;
DB::select("SELECT * FROM view_name WHERE estado = ?",[$estado])
```